# Is there anything wrong with this many-to-many Fluent Nhibernate mapping?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

i have this:

```
<set name="Identities" table="tIdentityGroups" inverse="true" batch-size="10" cascade="none">
      <cache usage="read-write" />
      <key column="GroupID" />
      <many-to-many class="Identity" column="IdentityId" />
</set>
```

and have translated it to this:

```
HasManyToMany<Identity>(x => x.Identities)
                .Table("tIdentityGroups")
                .ChildKeyColumn("IdentityID")
                .ParentKeyColumn("GroupID")
                .BatchSize(10)
                .Inverse()
                .Cascade.None()
                .Cache.ReadWrite();
```

The problem is that nothing is inserted in the tIdentityGroups table and my guess is that something is wrong with the mapping.

I dont know if the old nHibernate mapping worked before

Is there something i have done wrong with the new mapping or does the problem exist because of something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring it as `Inverse`, which means the *other* side of the relationship is responsible for maintaining it.

That means you need to add your **Group** to the **Identity**'s **Groups** property (which would not be `Inverse`) in order for the relationship to be persisted.

If you don't have a bidirectional relationship, remove the `Inverse`.